# How to use setOnPreferenceChangeListener for QuietlyCoding NumberPicker?

Tags: android, dialog

I want to detect when the value from the `NumberPicker` is changed. I have this code on my `PreferenceActivity`:

```
public class MainPrefs extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main_preferences);
        this.findPreference("SMSSentLimit").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
            new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                        Object newValue) {
                    TrackerService.updateStats(Long.decode(newValue.toString()));
                    return true;
                }
            });
        this.findPreference("NumberPickerLimit").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
            new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                        Object newValue) {
                    Log.i("onPreferenceChange", "NumberPicker Changed");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CHANGEEEED !!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The second one (`findPreference("NumberPickerLimit")`) is the `NumberPicker` and it is never called, if I change it to `onPreferenceClickListener` it works but I detect when I click the preference instead when I change the value.

Acording to source code it should be called:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                saveValue(mPicker.getCurrent());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

private void saveValue(int val) {
    getEditor().putInt(getKey(), val).commit();
    notifyChanged();
}
```

What´s happening? Is it a bug?

**EDIT**
Here is my XML:

```
<com.michaelnovakjr.numberpicker.NumberPickerPreference
            android:key="NumberPickerLimit"
            android:title="@string/NumberPickerTitle"
            android:summary="@string/NumberPickerSummary"
            picker:defaultValue="1"
            picker:startRange="1"
            picker:endRange="31" />
```

Comment: Your `SMSSentLimit` listener works?

Comment: Is the NumberPickerPreference successfully saving the value? When you change the number, close the dialog and reopen it, does it show the new number?

Comment: Yes it saves the value, it is calling saveValue() method but seems that notifyChanged() is not working

Answer (score 1):

Just looked at your xml file listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734221/how-to-use-numberpicker-from-quietlycoding-in-preferences/12734568#comment17205965_12734568), looks like you have `android:key="demo.preference"` there. Whereas in the code here, you're using `findPreference("NumberPickerLimit")`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the listener yourself. Instead of `notifyChanged()`, try `callChangeListener(val)` as seen here:

[`NumberPickerPreference`](https://code.google.com/p/standings/source/browse/trunk/trunk/com.michaelnovakjr.numberpicker.android/src/com/michaelnovakjr/numberpicker/NumberPickerPreference.java?r=8)