# How to check input in PreferenceActivity and prevent storing of invalid values?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, android-sharedpreferences

I have prepared a complete and simple test case for my question: [ValidatePrefs app at GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/ValidatePrefs):

[image: app screenshots]

When you click the "Settings" icon in the top right corner, [SettingsActivity](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/ValidatePrefs/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/validateprefs/) is displayed.

I would like to validate the 3 `EditTextPreference` fields by returning `true` or `false` from the `onPreferenceChange` method, but it is never called:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    private static final String TAG = SettingsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String ADDRESS   = "address";
    public static final String USERNAME  = "username";
    public static final String PASSWORD  = "password";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {    
        if (! (preference instanceof EditTextPreference)) {
            return false;
        }

        EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference)preference;
        String key = editTextPreference.getKey();
        String text = editTextPreference.getText();

        if (key == null || key.isEmpty() || text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (key) {
            case ADDRESS: {
                try {
                    new URI(text);
                } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            case USERNAME: {
                return text.length() > 0;
            }

            case PASSWORD: {
                return text.length() > 0;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After adding `findPreference` and `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` calls in the [SettingsActivity](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/ValidatePrefs/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/validateprefs/) the method `onPreferenceChange` is finally called:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceBundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceBundle);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

    EditTextPreference address = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(ADDRESS);
    EditTextPreference username = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(USERNAME);
    EditTextPreference password = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(PASSWORD);

    address.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    username.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    password.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

However I still can not validate and prevent saving wrong data, because the `text` variable contains the **old** value.

You can see it in the debugger screenshot below - I enter the new (and invalid) value of an empty string, but the variable `text` still contains the **old** value of `user1`:

[image: debugger]

**UPDATE 2:**

Okay, I was wrongly inspecting the old value stored in `Preference`, I should have looked at the new value, passed as 2nd argument to `onPreferenceChange` method. Here the fixed version of the method in my [SettingsActivity](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/master/ValidatePrefs/app/src/main/java/de/afarber/validateprefs/):

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object obj) {
    if (!(preference instanceof EditTextPreference && obj instanceof String)) {
        return false;
    }

    EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference)preference;
    String key = editTextPreference.getKey();
    String oldValue = editTextPreference.getText();
    String newValue = String.valueOf(obj);

    Log.d(TAG, String.format("key %s, value %s -> %s", key, oldValue, newValue));

    // TODO validate the newValue and return true or false
```

Comment: maybe use TextWatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However that method is never called.

It seems to me you have forgotten to register [`setOnPreferenceChangeListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setOnPreferenceChangeListener(android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener)), that's why the callback is not called.

Comment: Yes, but where to call that method in my app?

Comment: See usage in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12737724/1083957) question.