# Incorrect classpath to NumberPickerButton from Quietly Coding NumberPicker

Tags: android, dialog

I am developing an Android application for >= API 8.

For compatibility reasons, the application uses Actionbar Sherlock. Before API 11, the NumberPicker was an internal widget, but I need the NumberPicker, so I had to come up with another solution.

After some Googling, I stumbled upon this [NumberPicker](https://github.com/mrn/numberpicker) from Mike Novak. I implemented it but unfortunately, when I click on the preference that should bring up the dialog with the numberpicker, the application crashes.

It seems there is something wrong with the reference to the layout (logcat says `com.example.widget.NumberPicker` is used) file, but the source references to `com.michaelnovakjr.numberpicker.R.layout.pref_number_picker` as you can see [here](https://github.com/mrn/numberpicker/blob/master/lib/src/com/michaelnovakjr/numberpicker/NumberPickerPreference.java#L29).

**LogCat output:**

```
12-13 13:59:27.516: W/dalvikvm(11642): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40dbe930)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class com.michaelnovakjr.numberpicker.NumberPicker
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.preference.DialogPreference.onCreateDialogView(DialogPreference.java:343)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.preference.DialogPreference.showDialog(DialogPreference.java:287)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.preference.DialogPreference.onClick(DialogPreference.java:266)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:949)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:215)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    ... 23 more
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class com.example.widget.NumberPickerButton
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:459)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at com.michaelnovakjr.numberpicker.NumberPicker.<init>(NumberPicker.java:125)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at com.michaelnovakjr.numberpicker.NumberPicker.<init>(NumberPicker.java:117)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    ... 26 more
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.widget.NumberPickerButton" on path: /data/app/nl.livecarb.android-1.apk
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
12-13 13:59:27.555: E/AndroidRuntime(11642):    ... 31 more
```

**res/xml/main_preferences.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:picker="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/nl.livecarb.android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_cat_title_medical" >
        <com.michaelnovakjr.numberpicker.NumberPickerPreference
            android:key="@string/pref_key_ratio"
            android:summary="Bla"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_ratio"
            picker:defaultValue="1"
            picker:endRange="31"
            picker:startRange="1" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_cat_title_other" >
        <Preference
            android:key="@string/pref_key_disclaimer"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_disclaimer" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceClickListener {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment(), "settings").commit();
        } else {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main); 
        }
    }

    class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        private Preference preferences = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.main);

            preferences = findPreference(getResources().getString(R.string.pref_key_disclaimer));
            preferences.setOnPreferenceClickListener(SettingsActivity.this);
        }
    }
}
```

The error 
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.widget.NumberPickerButton" on path: /data/app/nl.livecarb.android-1.apk` doesn't make any sense to me, since I never used `com.example.widget.NumberPickerButton`. Neither the NumberPicker lib does.

Things I did trying to solve this problem:

1. [How to use NumberPicker from QuietlyCoding in preferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734221/how-to-use-numberpicker-from-quietlycoding-in-preferences)
2. Double checked the library project is referenced correct
3. Cleaned the project (including all libs)

Any thoughts?

Comment: this is `com.michaelnovakjr.numberpicker `your package ? if not then use your own package instead of this

Comment: I would like to use the widget `NumberPickerPreference`, which is included in the library, that is package `com.michaelnovakjr.numberpicker`. I could merge his project into mine, but that should not be the idea of a lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working off the master branch of the project? Try searching your code for a reference to that example package. I just took a look in the library and I don't see any reference to it.

Comment: It was my fault indeed... I was experimenting with some other NumberPickers, and I forgot to remove one of the layoutfiles containing `com.example.widget.NumberPicker`. Thanks for pointing out!